# Flattening a Map to varargs String list in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, variadic-functions, flatten

A Java event logging (analytics) library has a method that takes an event name and then varargs list of Strings like this:

```
Analytics.event("my event name", "key1", "value1", "key2", "value2" ...)
```

I've collected my event parameters in to a Map like

```
Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2" ...)
```

Now there must be a way to flatten the `Map` to list where keys and values alternate and then feed it to the event method. I've had several guesses, like transforming the `Map` to list a `List` of `Tuple`s, but calling .flatten on that says

```
No implicit view available from (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) => scala.collection.TraversableOnce[B]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `: _*` operator:

```
def event(name: String, values: String*) {/*...*/}

val params = Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2")
val paramsArr = params flatMap {case(k, v) => List(k, v)} toArray

event("name", paramsArr: _*)
```

Not sure whether this works with Java varargs as well (let us know!)

Comment: Thank you! Works exactly as supposed. The toArray (or toSeq) in the end was needed before :_* to get it to the format required by the java varargs.

Answer (score 6):

You can use flatMap to map every key/value pair to a list with two elements and then concatenate these lists.

```
scala> Map("k1" -> "v1", "k2" -> "v2")
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2)

scala> res0.flatMap { case (k,v) => k::v::Nil }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[java.lang.String] = List(k1, v1, k2, v2)
```

Once you have that, you can just pass the list to the event method:

```
Analytics.event("my event name", res1:_*)
```

Comment: Thanks. res:_* will produce Iterable and Intellij tells me it's Seq that's required here.

Answer (score 1):

```
val m = Map ("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "k3"-> "v3")
val li = m.map ((e)=> List (e._1, e._2)).flatten.toSeq 
event ("name", li: _*)
```

Comment: Quite similar to my answer, but 1 hour later and using map and flatten instead of flatMap. What's the point?

Comment: I forgot to hit return. Since it uses a different syntax, I kept it online. A reason to vote it down?